# Angular 2 - Define a ngAfterViewInit for all components

Tags: angular

In my Angular2 application, I have to call a script after the initialization of each component when the view is available.

I'm looking for the best way to define the "ngAfterViewInit" lifecycle callback globaly for all components . I can't write it in each component because there is a huge change that someone in the team forget it.

What I have considered:

- override @Component, if possible
- use routing

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: how about abstract class?

Comment: If you just fear someone forgets to write a ngAfterViewInit method, why don't you write a unit test or a pre-commit hook that checks that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an abstract Class and then extend all your components(classes) from that Class.

Something like :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export abstract class AbstractViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('after View init');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: 'I am a child'
})
export class ChildComponent extends AbstractViewInit {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1> <child></child>'
})
export class AppComponent extends AbstractViewInit {}
```

Working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/Lmyes9vmUosGS5shvHqA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be an acceptable solution. 
Also thanks to @kit who proposed the same solution